# How to get the likes and comments on a facebook post after a given timestamp?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to find out the latest comments and likes on a facebook page given a timestamp. Is there a way we can fetch this data from the facebook API? For example : If a user A posted something on my page 30 days back, and user B liked the post and commented on it today. I need to get these activities in the response if I try and find out all activities on my page in the past 2 days (even if the post is 30 days old).

Answer (score 1):

That is not working via the API, the **since** parameter only works on posts. A possibility is:

```
comments_after_that_time = 1349285260;

$comments = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/[yourpost_id]/comments?access_token=xxx"));

foreach($comments->data as $comment)
{
    if(strtotime($comment->created_time) > comments_after_that_time)
    {
    echo "we have a new comment";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I already had this plan as a backup for both - comments as well as likes. I was just looking if there was a way to get it using the Graph API. Anyways thanks for the solution.